# Backbone Js + Require Js + AmCharts

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs, amcharts

I am using backbone Js with require Js and design few charts using amCharts.

I included amCharts in shim as

```
shim:{
        amcharts:{
            deps: [
                'jquery''
            ],
        },
```

and path as:

```
paths:{
        jquery:'../lib/jquery.min',
        amcharts:'../lib/amcharts',
```

I could see in console that amCharts is getting loaded but none of the charts are displayed on the browser.

Then a colleague of mine included the amCharts js in html itself using script tag and Charts started to come.

Anybody know what could be the reason the charts didn't come. I don't want to include amCharts library in HTML.

Comment: in shim part of require config, for scripts that do not support AMD you shoud specfiy export which refernce to golabl object created by your scripts. for exmple 
    shim:{ backbone : {exports: 'Backbone' } }

Comment: Hi @Himen , i have kept exports now, but still it is not coming. There is another thing i should tell you, if i leave the page ideal for some time say 2 mins and then refresh the page, charts gets loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to write shim and export for that library. Maybe try giving quotes like -  'amcharts' in paths and shims.

```
'shim': {
    'amcharts': {
                deps: ['jquery'],
                exports: 'amcharts'
            }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you load amCharts asynchronous or in other words it's not a part of the document payload to catch the DOM:load event you need to set the ready state manually.

```
AmCharts.isReady = true;
```